# How does one set the `idle sensitivity` of Windows 11?

Tags: hibernate, windows-11, multimedia, standby

Essentially, when only playing music, whether via Spotify, VLC, Groove, etc., Windows11 will seemingly ignore or not receive messages to prevent idling.

I have verified that the Power Options::Advanced Settings::Multimedia Settings includes that "When sharing media" the system is to "Prevent idling to sleep".

As such, unless there is a better suggestion, I want to alter the threshold at which Windows perceives the computer being idle.